# Punctuation when slicing string in python with stride

Tags: python, string, slice, punctuation, stride

For the following code, why is the answer not 'yoif!' with the exclamation mark?

```
>>> s = 'Python is fun!'

>>> s[1:12:3]

>'yoif'
```

Why is the exclamation mark excluded, since it also has an index number, as shown by the following code (continued from above)?

```
>>> s[13]

>'!'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Try to read @Chris_Rands link and then maybe try `s[1::3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s = 'Python is fun!'`

`s[1:12]` only returns string till `'ython is fu'` hence a stride of 3 can't reach `!`

Where as

`s[1:14]` returns string till `'ython is fun!'`.

```
s[1:14:3]
```

output: `'yoif!'`

As [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) in the comment on the question by @Chris_Rands:

```
a[start:end] # items start through end-1
a[start:]    # items start through the rest of the array
a[:end]      # items from the beginning through end-1
a[:]         # a copy of the whole array

a[start:end:step] # start through not past end, by step
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that is how slicing works. It will pick the elements with indices starting at 1 and ending at max 12. Therefore, the only elements you see is of indices 1, 4, 7 and 10. 13 is the next step, but since it is above 12 so it will not show.

Answer (score 0):

Your question provides the answer itself. You are slicing from 1st to 12th position(which is not inclusive). so you will get elements upto 11th position.

if you want to get `!` change the value from 12 to 14. see below code.

```
s = 'Python is fun!'
print(s[1:14:3])
```

output:

```
'yoif!'
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `1` as the start of your sliced string, `12` at the end and `3` as the step. This is the general structure for slicing: `[start:end:step]`

With a start of `1` and a end of `12`, your string looks like this: `ython is fu`

You have to set your end at the right position. So `s[1:14]` would print `ython is fun!`

When you add your step of `3` like this `s[1:14:3]` your code prints `yoif!` as you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Slices, 0 indexed, are in the form [from : up to but not including : every]

To include the last element, exclude it from your slice and leave that part empty.

`>>> "Python is fun!"[1::3]
'yoif!'`

leaving 'from' empty makes it start at the beginning.

Leaving 'to' empty makes it go to the end.

`"Python is fun!"[:]
'Python is fun!'`